# Having trouble with SQL COUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, count, group-by

I'm using MS SQL 2008 and I have a table of statuses (id, name) and a table of items (id, name, statusid, deleted).

I want to count the number of items with each status, and have the following query:

```
SELECT status.id,
ISNULL(COUNT (items.name), 0) AS 'count'
FROM status
LEFT OUTER JOIN items
ON items.statusid = status.id
GROUP BY status.id
```

The complication is that I want to get all the statuses, with a 0 if there are no items for the status.

The above works fine for this, but when I add in `WHERE items.deleted = 0`, it no longer displays the rows with a 0 in them.

Why is the `WHERE` clause killing my query? I suspect my method may be wrong...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  status.id,
        COUNT (items.statusid) AS 'count'
FROM    status
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        items
ON      items.statusid = status.id
        AND items.deleted = 0
GROUP BY
        status.id
```

> Why is the `WHERE` clause killing my query? I suspect my method may be wrong...

Because if there are no items with given `statusid`, `LEFT JOIN` returns a single row with all items fields set to `NULL`.

Your `WHERE` clause filters these rows out (`NULL = 0` returns `NULL`) and they don't get into the `GROUP BY`.

Also note that `ISNULL` on `COUNT` is useless: `COUNT` never returns `NULL` values. It just doesn't count `NULL`s, so putting a column that is a part of a `JOIN` clause into `COUNT` wil do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there may not be an `items` row to reference, as it's across the outer join; you could try recasting your WHERE clause using ISNULL:

```
WHERE ISNULL(items.deleted, 0) = 0
```